# Cannot restart my pc while trying to do so from my ubuntu dual booted with windows 11

Tags: dual-boot, reboot

my pc not restarting from the ubuntu dual booted OS, while I am able to restart my PC when I was using Windows, but from ubuntu, restarting it goes in an infinite loop, it never restarts.

Comment: What does this mean "restarting it goes in an infinite loop, it never restarts." ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.